# iOS 10 Speech recognition `kAFAssistantErrorDomain` error codes

Tags: ios, speech-recognition, ios10, apple-speech

Where can I find definitions for different error codes with in `kAFAssistantErrorDomain` in iOS 10 Speech Recognition API?

Comment: I want to know this too - I can't find them anywhere!

Comment: I have this type of error shown whenever the user didn't speak anything, or when I am using SpeechRecognition inside a loop. They don't allow to use it inside a loop, it is considered abuse, or spamming the API.

Answer (score -3):

Speech Recognition API seems doesn't work properly with Swift versions lower than 3. If this is your case you have to migrate your code to Swift 3.0.

Comment: It's not the case, I need to know the definitions for the error codes.